# Ubuntu update and LibreOffice is taking a long time

Tags: updates, libreoffice

After I updated Ubuntu 18.04 LibreOffice writer is taking a very long time to paste an email. I thought it might be the writer, but I removed and installed an earlier version and it is doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that the e-mail application is checked in Libreoffice ?
For example, in Tools->Options->internet->e-mail I have the email program /usr/bin/thunderbird %u as the default option.
Also you must check that in the System preferences->Applications that you have the email program as default. Because I do not know what Desktop Environment you are using I could say anymore.
Regards

Comment: I will try that and see if it helps. Everything was working fine before the last update.